# How to join three tables together in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a table location that stores countries, provinces and cities.
I want when search a city by its id; I can see its province and country too! I have tried too much but I really don't know what exact query I need to write.

My table name is location and these are my fields with example data:

```
id             enName         localName   type     in_location
1              Iran              ایران    country          0
2              Fars             فارس      province         1
3              shiraz         شیراز       city             2
4              marvdasht        مرو دشت    city            2
```

I want when I search id = 3 get this results:

> country / province / city
>
> Iran / Fars / Shiraz

How I can write this query? I know I must join the table for 3 times but don't know how exactly do that.

The code I have tried :

```
SELECT 
    in_location ,
    enName 
FROM 
    location 
WHERE 
    id = 12321 as a
INNER JOIN
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        `fzxit_location` as b 
    on a.in_location = b.id
```

Comment: Mysql does not have any functionality to do hierarchical query. You can achieve this however if the hierarchy level is predefined. An easier way would be to write a recursive function on PHP to achieve what you are trying.

Comment: Your query defeats the purpose of relational databases, the rows in a same table shouldn't be directly related.

Comment: why are you trying to inner join the same table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WHERE statment should always come at the end. I think this is what your looking for. You'll be fixed for relationships with 3 children or less though.

```
SELECT a.enName, b.enName, c.enName FROM location as a
LEFT JOIN location as b ON a.in_location = b.id
LEFT JOIN location as c ON b.in_location = c.id
WHERE a.id = 3
```

Comment: You are 30 seconds faster :)

Answer (score 1):

Although you have not specified other Tables name, you can try this..

```
select a.countryName, 
       b.proviceName, 
       c.cityName 
from ((country a 
         left join province b on a.countryId = b.countryId) 
         left join city c on a.countryId = c.countryId) 
where id = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

this query may help you!

```
select from p.province_name,
            ct.country_name,
            c.city_name 
from city as c 
   INNER JOIN provinces as p ON c.province_id=p.province_id 
   INNER JOIN countries as ct ON c.country_id = ct.country_id 
where c.city_id = "requested value";
```

Comment: When indented nicely for readability, your error becomes quite obvious